# How to use ICS with multiple VMs without losing the explictly set IP addresses for each VM's Network Interface

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, icalendar, vmware-workstation

I am using VMware Workstation on a Windows 10 machine to add a Ubuntu Server and a Windows Server VM. This is to complete a virtual networking (firewall packet filtering) exercise using GNS3. The goal is to have 3 separate networks routed using virtual CISCO routers so I really need to have the IP of machines explicitly set to simulate different networks.

All of this is fine and I can ping from the host to the machines and the machines to the host but I'd also like to *somehow* be able to access Internet through each of the machines.

When I use Internet Connection Sharing and specify a single virtual adapter it warns me and changes the IP range to 192.168.137.x which is not desirable. When I want to use ICS for both VMs I create a bridged connection and apply ICS to that but again it changes my IP settings.

Is there a way I can share my hosts Internet Connection with each of the machines but keep the IP addresses and ranges I require?

Or, do I have to approach this a completely different way?

BTW, I'm using the Network Adapter type of 'Host Only' rather than Bridged or NAT as I cannot explicitly set IP addresses on those options.

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking it.

Using VMware I simply had to add an additional device Network Adapter (under VM > Settings) with a type of NAT to enable the VM to share my host's Internet. Of course, the existing interfaces (with the explicitly set IPs) were kept in place so it did not affect my virtual networking environment.